# Add new page to iTextSharp's PdfStamper with template and fields

Tags: c#, .net, templates, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add new page to a PdfStamper but this code doesn't add the template pdf fields to the stamper.

```
private void InsertNewPage(PdfStamper stamper, int pageNumber)
{
    var pdfReader = new PdfReader(UrlTemplateBlankPage);

    pdfReader.SelectPages("1");

    stamper.InsertPage(pageNumber, pdfReader.GetPageSize(1));

    stamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber).AddTemplate(stamper.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, 1), 0, 0);

    //This code doesn't work because the code before is not adding the form
    var pdfFormFields = stamper.AcroFields;

    var fieldKeys = pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields.Keys;

    foreach (var k in fieldKeys.ToList())
    {
        pdfFormFields.RenameField(k, k + string.Format("_{0:000}", pageNumber));
    }
}
```

I searched online but I can't find an answer about my problem.
The PDF template I'm adding has some fields added with Acrobat. I can't attach the template but I can give you all informations.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how do you instantiate the stamper. This is an example about how to read a PDF template and assign it to the stamper:

```
var reader = new PdfReader(TEMPLATE_PATH);
var pdfOutput = new FileStream(PDF_OUTPUT_PATH, FileMode.Create)

var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, pdfOutput);
```

After that, you can set the fields using the SetField function:

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("FIELD1", "VALUE")
```

There is an option to make your fillable PDFs non-editable using:

```
stamper.FormFlattening = true;
```

Otherwise, your PDF still fillable.

Once you have finished working with your files, close them:

```
stamper.Close();
reader.Close();
```

There is an example about how to use iTextSharp's PdfStamper in the next link: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/679606/Filling-PDF-Form-using-iText-PDF-Library